# Si no hay contenido en la variable que no se imprima

Tags: php, variables

estoy haciendo un eCommerce y puse una variable llama 'descuento'. Lo que quiero hacer es, que cuando no haya contenido ahí dentro, que no se imprima (es decir, haya un style que le de display none), pero no me funciona. Ya probé con: if(!empty) y aún así no pude. Dejo el código.

```
<p class="price-discount">
                <?php if(!empty($item['descuento'])){
                    print $item['descuento'];
                    print '% OFF';
                }else{?>
                
                <style>.price-discount{display: none;}</style>
                <?php } ?>
 </p>
```

Comment: El estilo CSS se carga al cargar el recurso (el archivo). Para manipular el elemento mientras se ejecuta tu script, tendrías que ponerle un atributo style a la etiqueta (`<div style="<?php if (...) ...display:none ?>"`)

Comment: Perdona pero no entendí a que te refieres. Podrías darme un código que me sea de ayuda. Muchas gracias

Comment: El problema es que no se esconde el parrafo? o que sigue apareciendo `%OFF` aunque ho haya descuento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías guardar tus estilos `CSS` en una variable, según tu descuento, haciendo una comprobación.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
<?php 
$mi_estilo = ($item['descuento'] == '') 
    ? 'display: none;'
    : 'display: block;'
;
?>

<p class="price-discount" style="<?php echo $mi_estilo; ?>"> 
    <?php echo "{$item['descuento']} % OFF"; ?>                
</p>
```

Si lo que deseas es añadir los estilos en tu etiqueta `style` en el `head`, te dejo una alternativa.

```
<html>
<head>
    <
    <?php 
    $mi_estilo = ($item['descuento'] == '') 
        ? 'none;'
        : 'block;'
    ;
    ?>
    <style>
        .price-discount {
            display: <?php echo $mi_estilo; ?>;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>  
    
    <p class="price-discount"> 
        <?php echo "{$item['descuento']} % OFF"; ?>                
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A esto añadiría que la etiqueta `<style>` sólo va en el head, no se usa en el body de un documento HTML.

Comment: @Alfabravo según tengo entendido hay tres formas de aplicar `CSS`, en este caso añadiendo el atributo `style` a una etiqueta `HTML` se llama como **INLINE CSS**, dejo un enlace: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Me explico: estoy totalmente de acuerdo con tu respuesta. Que la voté positiva y tal. Pero el OP estaba usando un `inline CSS` inválido, porque no le está poniendo el atributo a la etiqueta, sino que está poniendo una etiqueta `<style>` dentro de la etiqueta que quiere modificar. [(Referencia en MDN, que me gusta más que W3Cschools)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)

Comment: @Alfabravo, tienes razón que la OP está usando la etiqueta `<style></style>`, aun así, como tiene su estructura es un poco confusa ya que va dentro del párrafo `<p>`, dejare un segundo ejemplo. Un saludo amig@

Comment: Me da error, ya que si pongo lo de mi estilo en el head detecta la variable como indefinida, ya que se define luego en el documento. Intenté ponerla luego de que la definí pero no se vá

Comment: @Fabricio has probado el primer ejemplo? Ya que si tienes varios ítems no te va funcionar el segundo ejemplo. Si haces un `echo "$item['descuento'];` en caso que no tiene descuento que valor devuelve `0`? Luego que estilos tiene `.price-discount` en tu hoja de estilos? También podrías probar `$mi_estilo = (!isset($item['descuento']))`

Answer (score 0):

Aplica el estilo directamente en la etiqueta del párrafo:

```
<p class="price-discount"<?php if(empty($item['descuento']) { echo ' style="display:none;"'} ?>>
            <?php if(!empty($item['descuento'])){
                print $item['descuento'];
                print '% OFF';
            } ?>
</p>
```

O, mejor aún, solo coloca el *if* antes de crear el párrafo, si hay valor, entonces lo muestras:

```
<?php if(!empty($item['descuento'])){
    <p class="price-discount">
            <?php
                print $item['descuento'];
                print '% OFF';
            ?>
    </p>
<?php } ?>
```